# How can I group by the country in column two and then sort by the resulting sum?

Tags: scripting, sort

I have the file like:

```
1   UA
2   GB
3   UA
3   UA
2   US
1   UA
4   US
```

How can I group by the second column and sum by the first one? So the output should be like:

```
8 UA  
6 US
2 GB
```

Answer (score 2):

With `GNU awk`:

```bsh
$ awk 'BEGIN{PROCINFO["sorted_in"] = "@val_num_desc"}
       {a[$2]+=$1} END{for(k in a) print a[k], k}' ip.txt
8 UA
6 US
2 GB
```

See [gawk manual: Using Predefined Array Scanning Orders](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Controlling-Scanning) for details about the sorting options.

With `perl`:

```bsh
perl -lane '$h{$F[1]}+=$F[0]; END{print "$h{$_} $_" for
            sort {$h{$b} <=> $h{$a}} keys %h}' ip.txt
```

Comment: Thanks man, you're genius!

Answer (score 0):

Using GNU `datamash`:

```
$ datamash -W -s -g 2 sum 1 <file
GB      2
UA      8
US      6
```

This treats whitespaces as field delimiters, sorts the input on the second field, groups it on this field and sums the first field for each group.

Pipe the output through `awk '{ print $2, $1 }'` if you want to swap the columns (`datamash` always writes the grouping column first in its output), and `sort -nr` if you want to sort that output in decreasing order as in your example:

```
$ datamash -W -s -g 2 sum 1 <file | awk '{ print $2, $1 }' | sort -nr
8 UA
6 US
2 GB
```

Using `awk` for the summation:

```
$ awk '{ sum[$2] += $1 } END { for (i in sum) print sum[i], i }' file
8 UA
2 GB
6 US
```

Pass this through `sort -nr` to sort, as above.

Comment: thanks, my issue is solved

Comment: @PabloRyabolus If so, you need to accept one of the answers.  See https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers